# I am trying to implement multiGet operation in Spring on Redis, it throws me an error

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to execute `multiGet` function in Spring on Redis. It throws me an error. I have implemented `get` function successfully but while implementing `multiGet` it asks me for a Collection as second parameter. I am not sure what to enter? Can someone please guide me here.

Here is my code for multiGet()

Method definition:

```
@Override
 public User findById_MultiGet(String id) {
    return (User)hashOperations.multiGet("USER", id);
 }
```

Code In Controller :

```
@GetMapping("Map/MultiGet/{id}")
 public User allMultiGet(@PathVariable("id") final String id)    {
    // MultiGet function
    return userRepository.findById_MultiGet(id);
}
```

Error for above multiget method is `multiget(Object, Collection) type not (String,String) type`

Below code for Get function is working.

```
public User findById(String id) {
    return (User)hashOperations.get("USER", id);
 }
```

Code In Controller for Get function :

```
@GetMapping("Map/Get/{id}")
public User allGet(@PathVariable("id") final String id) {
 // Get function
    return userRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `multiGet` the second parameter should be a `Collection` like a `List` (in case you want the values of the list returned as result on the same positions as their belonging keys in the input list) or a `Set`.

In your example this would be something like this:

```
List<Object> values = hashOperations.multiGet("USER", Arrays.asList("id", "name")); 
Object id = values.get(0);
Object name = values.get(1);
```